# How do I prevent images from appearing to be selected when clicked in a PhoneGap application?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, webview

When the user taps on an image added to the PhoneGap app as follows, the image appears to be selected

```
<img src="image.png" onclick="action()">
```

This is on Android 4.1.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS add:

```
* {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

and that should disable the tap highlight for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `div` tag to prevent selection and dragging of image. Here is a sample code

```
<div style='background: url("image.png");" />
```